# pdo mysql with php loop only returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

UPDATE 2 - I managed to do it by using a subquery, rather than having a $config var with each number i added a row to my articles_category table to have 1 or 0, if it has 1 include it like so:

```
    $db->sqlquery("SELECT a . * , c.`category_name`
FROM `articles` a
LEFT JOIN `articles_categorys` c ON c.`category_id` = a.`category_id`
WHERE a.`active` =1
AND a.`category_id`
IN (
(

SELECT `category_id`
FROM `articles_categorys`
WHERE `show_in_rss` =1
)
)
ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
LIMIT ?", array($limit));
```

UPDATE1 - I have a partial solution i need help with the second bit (i don't even know if this is going the right way about it but it's driving me nuts).

If i do this;

```
    $category_array = explode(',', $config['article_rss_categorys']);

$in_sql = '';
$counter = 0;
// count how many there are
foreach($category_array as $cat)
{


    if ($counter == 0)
    {
        $in_sql .= '?';
    }

    else
    {
        $in_sql .= ',?';
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

I can put "$in_sql" inside the IN () to give me the individual ? and it works. Now i need to find a way to get each number from inside $config['article_rss_categorys'] into the second part of the query?

ORIGINAL;

$db is my database class/connection (all the functions are in this class).

Okay so here is my query:

```
$db->sqlquery("
    SELECT a.*, c.`category_name`
    FROM `articles` a LEFT JOIN `articles_categorys` c
    ON c.`category_id` = a.`category_id`
    WHERE a.`active` = 1
    AND a.`category_id` IN (?)
    ORDER BY a.`date`
    DESC LIMIT ?", array($config['article_rss_categorys'], $limit)
);
```

I check and the `$config['article_rss_categorys']` is set and its `0,1,2,4,6,7`, also `$limit` is set and it's `15`.

Here is my query code (inside the mysql class called by $db);

```
    try
    {
        $this->STH = $this->database->prepare($sql);

        foreach($objects as $k=>$p)
        {
            // +1 is needed as arrays start at 0 where as ? placeholders start at 1 in PDO
            if(is_numeric($p))
            {
                $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, (int)$p, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->STH->bindValue($k+1, $p, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        return $this->STH->execute();

        $this->counter++;
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $core->message($e->getMessage());
    }
```

I tested the query in phpmyadmin replacing `?` with the correct stuff and it does work so the database is fine.

I then try to fetch and put out the results like so;

```
while ($line = $db->fetch())
{
    // make date human readable
    $date = $core->format_date($line['date']);

    $output .= "
        <item>
            <title>{$line['category_name']} > {$line['title']}</title>
            <link>http://www.prxa.info/index.php?module=articles_comments&amp;aid={$line['article_id']}</link>
            <pubDate>{$date}</pubDate>
            <guid>http://www.prxa.info/index.php?module=articles_comments&amp;aid={$line['article_id']}</guid>
        </item>";
}
```

This is my fetch code (inside the mysql class called by $db);

```
public function fetch()
{
    $this->STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    return $this->STH->fetch();
}
```

It only returns one row, the last one. It is supposed to be looping through them all up to a max of 15.

I don't get why it's only getting one?

Comment: Did you try running the query manually - just to make sure it returns more than 1 result ?

Comment: @alfasin He wrote that he tested it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can bind a placeholder to an array like that. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: It's not an array though, it's just numbers seperated by commas.

Comment: but you're binding multiple values, maybe only the last one sticks, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm why does it get counted as multiple values? Because of the commas?

Comment: actually ignore that I'm most of the way through a bottle of wine and not thinking straight. I'll come back to this tomorrow if you don't have a solution. :)

Comment: Okay thanks i appreciate all the help i have this page bookmarked.

Comment: `array($config['article_rss_categorys'])` is an array. Maybe you just want `$config['article_rss_categorys']`

Comment: No it needs to be an array as the query code sorts through it. The $config var isn't an array itself though.

Comment: Please see my update at the top, partial soluton, just need the second bit.

Answer (score 1):

[PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) only returns one row, you need [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

See http://www.php.net/pdo

Comment: The problem is it works elsewhere in my script, since it's in a loop shouldn't it keep going?

Comment: You don't show where you call fetch(), but its the usual mistake. Could you show that code?

Comment: Why does everything except fetch() in the while loop refer to $this->STH?

Comment: Also you are returning the last row with `return $this->STH->fetch();` in the last snippet. That's the one you describe as your 'fetch code'.

Comment: STH is because i followed this to learn PDO http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/, it's the statement. The while loop and query are outside of the class those functions are in. So i'm calling them in. The code snippets are not in order it being run, the fetch function is called in the while loop it should give me all the rows but it gives me the last one. I also tried it with fetch all, same result, the last one. So i think the query is the problem.

Comment: In your fetch() function do a var_dump($this->STH->fetchAll()) and put the result into your question please. It could be that [@barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868229/pdo-mysql-with-php-loop-only-returning-1-row/12868274#comment17419660_12868229) is right. If so, I will delete this answer and he can post his own.

Comment: Please see my update at the top, partial soluton, just need the second bit.